# If a ZIP file is requested, how do you how to get it from fiddler?

Tags: api-testing

If you request a service send you a zip file as response, then how do you retrieve the file from fiddler?

Comment: Hassan, can you explain what this has to do with QA or testing? We do cover testing tools, but I'm on the fence whether Fiddler is a QA tool or a dev tool.

Answer (score 1):

Within Fiddler, hit the *Decode* button:

[image]

When this is set, if Fiddler receives a response in the form of a ZIP archive, it will be decompressed.